# ¿Como hacer una lamada ajax usando jquery a una funcion PHP que esta dentro de una clase?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando hacer una una llamada ajax, a una funcion PHP que esta dentro de una clase, el archivo php se llama GAlumnos.php, hasta el momento sigo  fracasando.Ayuda!!![image: ![Este es la consulta]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dJ8u.gif)

[image: funcion PHP (Buscar), esta dentro de un clase GAlumnos, el archivo php se llama GAlumnos.php]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow, donde [un fragmento de código vale más que mil imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2990/29967). Por favor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/135981/edit) poniendo el texto con el código en lugar de las imágenes. Y tenlo en cuenta para futuras preguntas. También, no digas solamente que estás fracasando, di cuál es el fracaso, que error da, qué mensaje muestra, etc. Gracias. En cuanto al código, en la `url` que pasas en el Ajax aparece un código imposible de ejecutar. Llamar a un PHP seguido de barras, no tiene sentido.

Comment: En base a lo que escribes solo te puedo decir, imagina que cuando haces la llamada ajax, estas ejecutando un archivo desde 0 osea debes crear tus instancias (de ser necesario).

Comment: Creo te estas saltando un paso. Necesitas in archivo php intermedio que funcione como controlador, sea quien reciba la llamada vía AJAX, instancie la clase GAlumno, se llame a la funcion Buscar psra que devuelva el json que espera tu javascript

Comment: Creo te estas saltando un paso. Necesitas in archivo php intermedio que funcione como controlador, sea quien reciba la llamada vía AJAX, instancie la clase GAlumno, se llame a la funcion Buscar psra que devuelva el json que espera tu javascript

Comment: ¿Es esto es un ejercicio o parte de un tutorial o algo? No por nada pero, si no recuerdo mal, hace unos días otro usuario hizo una pregunta exactamente igual a esta. ¿Has buscado en el sitio?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que la declaración de una Clase no hace que se ejecute, quiero decir que puede tener por ejemplo:

```
Class xxx {}
```

y luego debajo de la clase tendrías que crear ese objeto y llamar a la función que necesites:

```
$c = new xxx();
echo $c->buscar($search);
```

De esta forma al ejecutar el resultado del archivo es la impresión del resultado de la función buscar.

Hay muchas formas mas elegantes de hacer esto, pero para tu problema digamos que es suficiente.

Comment: Gracias por responder,  por favor podrías darme un ejemplo de la otra forma que dices, o recomendarme alguna pagina que sea realmente bueno.

Comment: simplemente luego de tu clase GAlumnos, algo como: $galumnos = new GAlumnos(); y luego llama a buscar $galumnos->buscar(). Con eso ya lo tienes. De todas formas yo te recomendaría leer un poco de Composer para evitar realizar includes y require, que no es buena praxis.

Comment: okk, muchas gracias por la información.